# Why there is a logic error with this method. isPalindrome(11) should return true, but it returns false

Tags: java, methods, boolean, palindrome

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    
    int reverseNumber = 0;
    int lastDigit = 0;
    
    
    if (number < 0) {
        number = number * -1;
    }
    
    while (number > 0) {
        lastDigit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        if (number == 0) {
            reverseNumber += lastDigit;
        }
        else {
        reverseNumber += lastDigit;
        reverseNumber *= 10;
        }
    }
    return reverseNumber == number;
}
```

This method should return for true palindromes, but it doesn't.

Comment: You need to figure out how to debug code. One way would be to print out the values of 'number' and 'reversenumber' each time around the loop.

Comment: Consider: `return new StringBuilder().append(number).reverse().toString().equals(Integer.toString(number));`

Answer (score 1):

You are "destroying" the original `number` while constructing `reverseNumber`:

```
number = number / 10;
```

So after the `while`-loop, your `number` is zero, and the comparison `reverseNumber == number` doesn't work as you expect. It's always `false` unless your reverse number is zero.

You could use a new local variable for building `reverseNumber`, which you modify in the loop, but still use the original `number` for the final comparison:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {

   // ... Handle negatives

   int tempNumber = number; 

   while (tempNumber > 0) {
       // ...
       tempNumber = tempNumber / 10;
       // ...
   }

   return reverseNumber == number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is wrong because you have taken the variable `number` for all the process. So that the `number=11` get reduced during each time and finally when comparing with `reverseNumber`, it is comparing as `11 == 0`. So what the output is false.
Assign a variable `temp` like, `int temp = number` .

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {

int temp = number;
int reverseNumber = 0;
int lastDigit = 0;


if (number < 0) {
    number = number * -1;
}

while (number > 0) {
    lastDigit = number % 10;     
    number = number / 10;
    reverseNumber = (reverseNumber * 10) + lastDigit ;
}
return reverseNumber == temp;
```

}